# What are "reduction semantics"? Please explain the use of PLT Redex in layman's term

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages, racket, semantics, plt-redex

Somebody please explain the usage of reduction semantics and the PLT Redex in simpler language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reduction semantics is a computation technique that involves **replacing an expression by an equivalent (and hopefully smaller) expression** until no more replacement is possible.  If a language is Turing-complete, there are expressions that never stop replacing.

Reduction is usually notated by a right arrow, and it's best explained by example:

```
(3 + 7) + 5   -->  10 + 5  -->  15
```

This shows the standard reduction semantics for arithmetic expressions.  The expression `15` cannot be reduced any further.

Hope this helps.

Comment: See also the redex website (redex.plt-scheme.org) and the book that was published recently ("Semantics Engineering with PLT Redex").

Comment: @Norman: is reduction the same as the substitution model of evaluation ?

Answer (score 7):

Reduction semantics are similar (if not the same?) to contextual semantics.  Any expression can be broken down into a context and redex.

Robert Harper's Practical Foundations for Programming Languages (draft PDF available [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/)) section 9.3 Contextual Semantics does a decent job of explaining them.

An example:

```
print 5+4
**context: print [],  redex: 5+4
**evaluate redex: 9
**plug back into context

print 9
**context: [], redex: print 9
**evaluate redex: nil  ==> 9
**plug back into context

nil
```

You can 'stick' the redex back into the 'hole' of the context to get: print 5+4.  The evaluation happens at the redex.  You break an expression into a context + redex, evaluate the redex to get a new expression, plug that back into the context, rinse and repeat.

Here's a slightly more complicated example that requires knowledge of an abstract machine that evaluates the lambda calculus:

```
(lambda x.x+1) 5
**context: [] 5, redex: (lambda x.x+1)
**evaluate redex: <(lambda x.x+1), {environment}> <- create a closure
**plug back into context

<(lambda x.x+1), {}> 5
**context: [], redex: <(lambda x.x+1), {}> 5
**evaluate redex: x+1 where x:=5
**plug back into context

x+1 where x:=5
**context: []+1, redex: x
**evaluate redex: 5 (since x:=5 in our environment)
*plug back into context

5+1...
6
```

EDIT: The tricky part is recognizing where to break an expression into a context & redex.  It requires knowledge of the operational semantics of the language (which 'piece' of an expression you need to evaluate next).